# How to make a div resize while keeping aspect ratio of content inside same?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0g37mup/) for the code.

[I want the card stacks to look like this regardless of screen size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJDbS.png)
But currently, it's either overlapping or becoming too small. I have very limited understanding of css, But I am guessing that i need to use proper breakpoints to write css for each screen size, or maybe resize everything with viewport ?
 Using this to resize card stacks but am unable to align everything properly while doing that.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .petalgrid {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.2);
    -o-transform: scale(0.2);
    transform: scale(0.2);
  }
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 400px) {
  .petalgrid {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.4);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.4);
    -o-transform: scale(0.4);
    transform: scale(0.4);
  }
}
```

Comment: Given CSS code is not enough to clear your issue, So can you share your HTML code?